# success handling in ajax query not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb

i have this call for ajax query :
the problem is that when the function is run it is never go to to the success, i don't know why, i am only get some json object from my mongoDB but when i debug it it is allways skip over and not stop in the success function,

i am using NODEJS at my server side

even the work method is not work..

any help please ?

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/loadPre',
                type: 'GET',
                data: parameters,
                success:
                    function (presentation)
                    {
                        alert("work");
                        sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(presentation.jsonToSave), function (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                            scene = e.scene;
                        }, '.');
                    },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

and this is my code in my `index.js` at my node.js server side :

```
exports.loadPre = function (db)
{
    return function (req, res)
    {
        var NameOfPreToFind = req.body.Prename;

        var collection = db.get('PresentationCollection');

        collection.find({name: Prename}, {}, function (e, presentation) {
            res.render('preToLoad', {
                "preToLoad": presentation
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Is `name: Prename` supposed to be `name: NameOfPreToFind`? Also, can you show the `app.use()` line where you're using that particular custom middleware? Have you verified that your `collection.find()` callback is executed?

Comment: how do i verify that the find callback is executed? and yes name: Prename supposed to be name: NameOfPreToFind

Comment: I'd put some "console.log" entries in various points of the loadPre function to ensure it is getting called.